# Converting to file from Convert.ToBase64String

Tags: c#, file

I've converted a file using `Convert.ToBase64String` and saved to database.
But i've have problem in retrieving the file again.

Please help...

```
_copyLocation = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + "\\" +
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss") + ".sdf";


File.Copy(ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + "\\" + 
          "Data.sdf", _copyLocation);

byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_copyLocation);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
stream.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
```

Saved to database as:  `Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);`

Comment: I tried it.. But when i retrive from database, i get as a Byte Array. But Convert.FromBase64String accepts only string..

Comment: If this is SQL Server 2008 or higher you can use the BLOB data type to store binary data as a byte array directly. Also lookup Encoding.GetString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to convert.. 
Work fine.. :

```
  File.WriteAllBytes("1.sdf", Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3])));
```

Comment: Look up what `Encoding` means. You've got it completely wrong because you're forcing bytes into a string using ASCII encoding. Don't puzzle together sample code pieced until it *seems* to work.

Comment: Yes.. It works.. I opened the Sql compact database in SQL Manager. Data is good..

Comment: Try testing with the following string: "öäüßé".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.  There is nothing called `ds` in the original question, and the data is coming from the disk.

Comment: ds is the dataset which i fetched from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(_copyLocation))
```